# How to properly calculate the total sum of each die face

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem lies in calculating the sum total of all dice faces after they have finished rolling.

For example, the face of die one may give 4 as the result, and die two may give 5, but the total result will be 5, the value of die one is ignored, although it is detected as indicated in the log.

Often die face values are not taken into account in the calculation, and other times the previous value is not cleared before displaying the new result, and so the results accumulate.

Here's my code to calculate the total sum of the dice faces

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Linq;

public class DisplayCurrentDiceValue : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _valueText;
    private int totalDiceValue = 0;
    private bool isValueDisplayed = false;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        ResetTotalDiceValue();
        DiceManager.OnStopRolling += AddDiceValue;

        // Trouver le composant TextMeshProUGUI attaché à ce GameObject ou à un GameObject enfant
        if (_valueText == null)
        {
            _valueText = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        DiceManager.OnStopRolling -= AddDiceValue;
    }

    private void ResetTotalDiceValue()
    {
        totalDiceValue = 0;
    }

    private bool isNewRoll = true;

    private List<int> diceResults = new List<int>();

    private void AddDiceValue(int faceValue)
    {
        diceResults.Add(faceValue);
        totalDiceValue = diceResults.Sum();

        // Vérifier si tous les dés sont arrêtés
        if (IsAllDiceStopped() && !isValueDisplayed)
        {
            UpdateValueText();
            StartCoroutine(BounceInAnimation());
            isValueDisplayed = true;
            ResetDiceResults();
        }
    }

    public void ResetValueDisplayed()
    {
        isValueDisplayed = false;
    }

    private void ResetDiceResults()
    {
        diceResults.Clear();
    }

    private bool IsAllDiceStopped()
    {
        GameObject[] diceObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Dice");
        foreach (GameObject diceObject in diceObjects)
        {
            Rigidbody diceRigidbody = diceObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (diceRigidbody && !diceRigidbody.IsSleeping())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void UpdateValue()
    {
        UpdateValueText();
    }

    private void UpdateValueText()
    {
        _valueText.text = totalDiceValue.ToString();
    }
private IEnumerator BounceInAnimation()
{
   .......
}
}
```

I want all detected values to be taken into account and calculated and then displayed, and when there is a new run the previous values are correctly erased before being added.

Comment: as mentioned yesterday already, you should start using your debugger to see if your event-handler is hit. Put a breakpoint into it and see if it gets hit when running your code. Btw.: you're talking of some log, that we can't see.

Comment: The class DisplayCurrentDiceValue is supposed to add up the dice, it uses a diceResults object and the int totalDiceValue to do that. I can't see where diceResults is defined or what its lifetime is - your problem might be that diceResults is losing its state somewhere. Where is the diceResults object defined and when does it get reset?

Comment: The ResetDiceResults() method is called at the end of the AddDiceValue() method to clear all values stored in diceResults.

Comment: @Oueza I don't see diceResults declared anywhere. What holds a reference to it?

Comment: private List<int> diceResults = new List<int>();

Comment: Yes, the diceResults list has been declared as a member variable of the DisplayCurrentDiceValue class

Comment: @Oueza oh yeah I see it now. My best guess then, is that your DisplayCurrentDiceValue object is losing its state somehow and so it can't add the dice up properly. When does the DisplayCurrentDiceValue object get created and how long does it last for?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I solved the problem by setting up complex conditions